# Javascript Image-Resize before upload

Tags: javascript, client, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize big/large images on client and upload the smaller image. This works perfectly with one or ten images. But i want to upload mybe 50+ images. This will work but it slows down my cpu and memory. The code for the resized images is this:

```
        var MAX_WIDTH = 1920;
    var MAX_HEIGHT = 1920;
    var loaded = 0;
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;


    function loadImage(file) {
        var mime = file.type;
        var src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

       var img = new Image();

        img.onload = (function (image) {
            return function () {
                var newHeight = MAX_WIDTH;
                var newWidth = MAX_HEIGHT;


                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                canvas.width = newWidth;
                canvas.height = newHeight;



                ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);


                var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL(mime);
                var blob = dataURLToBlob(dataURI);
                imagesToUpload.push(blob);

                loaded++;
                if (loaded < checkedFiles.length) {
                    loadImage(checkedFiles[loaded]);
                } else {
                    //DO UPLOAD
                    input.value = "";
                }
            }
        })(img);
        img.src = src;
        image = null;

    }


    loadImage(checkedFiles[0]);
```

While resizing and uploading, i want to show a loading animation. And this anmiation is very slow.

I think the problem is while resizing the image on the canvas-object, but i have no idea to solve this issue.

The MAX-PICTURE-WITH is 1920px and the MAX-PICTURE-HEIGHT is 1920px.

It would be great if someone can give me a clue?